# CSS triangle :before element

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I'm using bootstrap, trying to make a div have a CSS triangle before it.

http://jsfiddle.net/B2XvZ/11/

Here is my non-working code:

```
.d:before {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px 15px 10px 0;
  border-color: transparent #dd4397 transparent transparent;  
}
```

The way I'd like it to look is for there to be a pink left-pointing triangle right before the text "this", with no gap between it and the div.  I've tried to do this by floating the elements also, with no success.

Comment: Add a `content` property.

Comment: To understand how this shape works and for alternative solutions please see http://stackoverflow.com/q/7073484/1811992

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transparent arrow/triangle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23758922/transparent-arrow-triangle)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You need to specify the `content` property.

For positioning, add `position:relative` to the parent, and then absolutely position the arrow `-15px` to the left.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/954h6/)

```
.d {
    position:relative;
}

.d:before {
    content:"\A";
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 15px 10px 0;
    border-color: transparent #dd4397 transparent transparent;
    position: absolute;
    left: -15px;
}
```

Comment: thank you, this also solved my problem. But what does the CSS ISO \A stand for?

Comment: @FrauWolf `\A` is a carriage return. I think I did that for some older browser quirk (probably IE). It's not needed anymore, though. `content: ''` would work just fine.

Answer (score 13):

You need content property and some other

```css
.d:before {
  content: '';
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px 15px 10px 0;
  border-color: transparent #dd4397 transparent transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class='fluid-container'>
  <ul class='foo'>
    <li class='bar row'>
      <div class='a'>asdf</div>
      <div class='b'>asdgf</div>
      <div class='c'>asj</div>
      <div class='d pull-right'>this needs a css triangle</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use UTF-8 Geometric Shapes.

```
a:before {
  content: '\25B2'
}
```

in your HTML need a meta charset:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" /> 
...
</head>
</html>
```

Geometric shapes list:
https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_geometric.asp

Comment: But you can't change the color then, right?

Answer (score 2):

```
a:after {
content: '';
width: 0px;
height: 0px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 15px 15px 0px 15px;
border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
position: absolute;
bottom: -13px;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
```

}